Can we CRUD and perform custom queries in Google Firestore with PHP?
I'm trying to connect PHP - codeigniter with google Firebase
as my android app has authentication with firebase,
my Web application will use the same Auth
its Firestore not real time database
I want to perform CRUD operation through PHP
I used the following links and code,
I can authenticate using the login and verify_id_token functions
But can't read collections
-- please read comment in AuthController->get_user_info()
I'm using
https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php
kreait/firebase-php
https://cloud.google.com/php/docs/reference/cloud-firestore/latest
google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;
this is my Helper.php
<?php

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\Auth;
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;

function firebase_auth() {
    static $auth = null;

    if ($auth === null) {
        $serviceAccount = __DIR__ . '/../config/somthing.json'; // Adjust path as needed
        $factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount);
        $auth = $factory->createAuth(); // Use the Factory from Kreait\Firebase
    }

    return $auth;
}

function create_firestore(string $projectId = null) {
    static $firestore = null;
    if ($firestore === null) {
        try {
            $serviceAccount = __DIR__ . '/../config/somthing.json';
            $firestore = new FirestoreClient([
                'projectId' => $projectId, // Set project ID if needed
            ]); // Directly create FirestoreClient
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Handle the exception, e.g., log the error or throw a custom exception
            echo "Error creating Firestore client: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    return $firestore;
}

This is my Authcontroller
<?php

use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;

class AuthController extends CI_Controller {
    private $logger;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->logger = new Logger('FirestoreLogger');
        $this->logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(APPPATH . 'logs/firestore_debug.log', Logger::DEBUG));
    }
    public function verify_id_token($idToken) {
        try {
            $auth = firebase_auth();
            $verifiedIdToken = $auth->verifyIdToken($idToken);
            return $verifiedIdToken->claims()->get('sub'); // Return the UID
        } catch (\Kreait\Firebase\Exception\AuthException $e) {
            echo "Token verification failed: " . $e->getMessage();
            return null; // Token verification failed
        } catch (\Kreait\Firebase\Exception\FirebaseException $e) {
            echo "Firebase error: " . $e->getMessage();
            return null; // Token verification failed
        }
    }

    public function login() {
        $email = 'nuked.hacker@gmail.com'; 
        $password = 'abc123';

        try {
            $auth = firebase_auth();

            // Attempt to sign in the user
            $signInResult = $auth->signInWithEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
            
            // Retrieve the ID token
            $idToken = $signInResult->idToken();

            // Store the ID token in session or return it to the client
            $_SESSION['idToken'] = $idToken; // Example of storing in session

            echo "User signed in successfully. ID Token: " . $idToken;

        } catch (\Kreait\Firebase\Exception\AuthException $e) {
            echo "Authentication failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        } catch (\Kreait\Firebase\Exception\FirebaseException $e) {
            echo "Firebase error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function get_user_info($uid) {
        // Retrieve the ID token from session or request
        $idToken = isset($_SESSION['idToken']) ? $_SESSION['idToken'] : null;

        // Verify the ID token
        $verifiedUid = $this->verify_id_token($idToken);

        if ($verifiedUid === null) {
            echo "User is not authenticated.";
            return;
        }

        // Check UID authorization
        if ($verifiedUid !== $uid) {
            echo "You are not authorized to access this user data.";
            return;
        }

        try {
            // Initialize Firestore
            $firestore = create_firestore('tracingapp-13543');

            // Attempt to access document
            $collection = $firestore->collection('users');
            $document = $collection->document($uid);
            $userDocument = $document->snapshot();

//when i use above line it shows me site can't be reached

            if ($userDocument->exists()) {
                $userData = $userDocument->data();
                echo "User Info: ";
                print_r($userData);
            } else {
                echo "User does not exist.";
            }
        } catch (\Kreait\Firebase\Exception\FirebaseException $e) {
            $this->logger->error("Firestore Error: " . $e->getMessage());
            echo "An error occurred. Check logs for details.";
        }
    }
}

what am i doing wrong
$userDocument = $document->snapshot();

this line says site isn't working
there is no error or debug any where, (apache logs, CI logs, monologs)
When print_r above code before this line, i.e $document i get an object
But when i use snapshot, it says site isn't working
Yes I can open firebase console
